# Css alerts not on top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some alert signs to go on top of one another, but on top of everything, I manage to make it to the top like a notification but when I have multiples alerts one goes on in front of the other.

here is my css

```
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  top: 10%;
  right: 16px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999999 !important;

.alert.success {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.alert.warning {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
```

and my html

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert">
        <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
        <strong>{{$error}}</strong>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Make a container for your alerts. Fix the `position` of the container, not the position of the alerts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Make a container that has the fixed position on it, then add the alerts to it.

Outcome:

[image]

```css
.alert-container {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  top: 10%;
  right: 16px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999999 !important;
}
.alert{
  padding: 20px;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:10px;

}
.success {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.warning {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert-container">
  <div class="alert success">success!</div>
  <div class=" alert warning">warning</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on J. Titus's comment,

`z-index` only works on positioned elements. An element is considered positioned if it is **not** `static`, `relative`, or `absolute`. Since `.alert` has `position: fixed`, the z-index does nothing.

Here is a link for full details on that 
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

By wrapping your alert in a container, you can give the alert a z-index while keeping the container fixed.