# Alert Messages are not displaying on top of all my html components

Tags: css, angular, alert

I'm displaying an alert message on my application that is following the page scrolling and is supposed to be on top of all other HTML elements. It's working fine, except that when it's scrolling over some part of html elements it's going behind. I want it to stay on top every time of course.
There are different components on my page one after each other, and I identified that it is dependent of the component it's scrolling over. What really puzzles me is that all the components use the same type of bootstrap (so is supposed to be the CSS obviously), and are pretty much the same for me. I don't why it's working on some, and not the others.

I tried to follow the "container fixed/alert z-index" idea, like in this post [Css alerts not on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811451/css-alerts-not-on-top)
That didn't work. I tried to define a lower z-index for the other components. That didn't work either. I look more precisely at the CSS of one element where it's passing over and another where it is not. I didn't identify anything that could explain.

Here is my Alert Message component:

```
<div *ngFor="let alert of alerts" class="{{ cssClass(alert) }} alert-dismissable"
 style="top: 0; right: 0;">
  {{alert.message}}
 <button type="button" class="close" (click)="removeAlert(alert)" style="margin-left: 5px">&times;</button>
</div>
```

The CSS of the alert message:

```
.alert {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    z-index: 999; ==> not working
 }
```

Where do you think I should look at? What could explain this?

Comment: Try to figure it out which style does the error. Set at your beginning of your own style in your root style, but after the framework style something like `* { z-index: 0; }` maybe then you know if it happens because of z-index.

when this is not the error then maybe your element flows under a `overflow: hidden; ` or better say a `overflow-y: scroll;` that means, that if you want to have it over all elements you have to set it `position: fixed;`

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your answer. So i tried * { z-index: 0; } test. It didn't change anything. So i guess it's not linked to the z-index. When you say 'your element', are you referring to the alert message ? Pardon my ignorance, but what's the link with the overflow:hidden/overflow-y: scroll and the fact that the message is going behind some of my HTML elements ? I tried with my message set to position: fixed, and it's still not working.

Comment: If you use maybe flex boxes and the box with the main content has something like that `overflow-y: scroll` your content will scroll inside the box, not withing the browsers default scroll bar. when you use `overflow:hidden;` your content dissapears if its growing bigger than the space available. i would recommend to  put the alert-handling in a central component with a service and put the element selector on button of the main html. then it should work.

Comment: here i found my last solution: https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/nearest-stars/tree/8a690b1218813f8a41cf13b283360aa07fea6e04/apps/client/src/app/comps/msgline

Comment: I solved it ! The idea to move the message component to another place was good. I 'll write the solution below. Thank you very much for your time and advices !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **JohnnyDevNull** advice i solved the issue. Unsurprisingly, the place of your alert component matters in order to display correctly above the others components.

So i took my

```
<app-message></app-message>
```

to a level above in my components path (in my case in the app.component.html) and it worked perfectly.